# running evince from root is so slow

Tags: sudo

For some specific reasons I need to run evince from command line as root, this is because certain files on my system as so protected that I can only access them via root.

Since by default is not possible to get the file by running the following command logged as root

```
evince filename.pdf
```

sometime ago I found the following workround, logged into terminal as root I can open the file with

```
xhost local:root
DISPLAY=$DISPLAY  evince  filename.pdf
```

what happens now is that the above command still work, but it takes like 1minute to open the file, whereas if do

```
sudo evince filename.pdf
```

it does it immediately.

Any explanation?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, it should not be necessary to elevate the Evince GUI to root, and doing so could be a serious security risk. You should ensure that the files you need to manage have the proper permissions and ownership attributes attached to them. You can look into `chmod` to adjust the permissions for the file and `chown` to adjust ownership. Setting this properly should ensure you don't need to use `sudo evince`.

*Here's an example, for a file on my system.*

**To set the file to the proper permissions, I'd use this:**

`sudo chmod 664 /home/schykle/myfile.pdf`

**To change my user to the owner of the file, I'd use this:**

`sudo chown schykle /home/schykle/myfile.pdf`